# Is there a good alternative to the original meaning of the word "thug"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As per [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151032/are-there-racial-overtones-for-the-term-thug) it seems that the word "thug" has become taboo (in at least some US subcultures) after being allegedly adopted for racist use.

Without going into the merits of the taboo, it seems to have become widespread enough that using the word on the internet may be unwise.  Is there a good alternative?

Someone mentioned "goon" in the linked question, but that's not right: in international English, at least, a "goon" works for someone whereas a "thug" is usually acting on his own behalf.  "Criminal" is too broad in one sense and too narrow in another, since "thug" was often used to describe someone whose behaviour was aggressive and socially unacceptable but not necessarily literally criminal.  "Hooligan" doesn't seem quite right either, though it is close.

As an example of the sort of context the word I'm asking for might be used in, [see this 1989 Calvin and Hobbes cartoon](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1989/07/01).

Comment: Most people in Britain know the etymology of this word. The original *thugs* were members of assassin bands in India - hired killers who strangled their victims. The reason it is so well known is that the fact of Britain having ended it was one of the factors which led to the Indian Mutiny. It is said to be similarly the case for Suttee, the requirement of a Hindu widow to immolate herself on her husband's funeral pyre. British liberal imperialism declared it to be barbaric, but when they stopped it the Indians mutinied.

Comment: I wonder if "petty thug" has a racist connotation.

Comment: In AusE "thug" still has currency, at least in newspaper headlines and stories, however "lout" is often also used, as is "hoon" (which specifically relates to aggressive and wild driving by young males, but can be used more broadly to cover other young, male anti-social behaviour).

Comment: In the US "thug" was simply a low-class criminal who was apt to hang out with gangsters and do their "dirty work".  I never knew of any sort of racial or ethnic connotation -- it was simply the sort of guy you were better off not knowing.  I suspect the word largely passed out of use ca 1970 when all the gangsters hired image consultants.

Comment: Of course, the problem with replacing the word is that "thug" has certain reverse onomatopoeia, in that it suggest hitting someone with, eg, a black-jack, and this was the image the word carried.  None of the suggested replacements have this attribute.

Comment: Just as an aside, in the *Calvin and Hobbes* cartoon, Calvin says: "I bet I'd have gotten ...", whereas in AusE this would nearly always be said: "I bet I would've got ...", since "gotten" is not grammatical.

Comment: @Cargill: in NZ we would likely say "gotten" in casual speech.

Comment: This is the first suggestion I have ever seen of *thug* being proscribed as politically incorrect. In Britain it has no racist implications whatever. It may stereotype and degrade the image of the class of people so described, but so far as I know it is neither illegal, nor politically incorrect to hold a prejudice against violent criminals.

Comment: @WS2: see the linked question, dated nearly two years ago; it isn't a brand new phenomena.  It isn't clear to me just how widespread it is, but I've seen it more than once now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of 'hoodlum' perhaps most closely matches the meaning of 'thug':

> **hood·lum**  (ho͞od′ləm, ho͝od′-) *n.*
>   1. A gangster; a thug.
>   2. A tough, often aggressive or violent youth.
>
> **thug**  (thŭg) *n.*
>   1. A cutthroat or ruffian; a hoodlum.
>   2. also Thug One of a group of professional criminals, devotees of Kali, who robbed and murdered travelers in northern India until the mid-1800s.

(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved December 1 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ .)

A number of other words might work:

- brute ("A brutal, crude, or insensitive person.")
- heavy ("*Slang* A mobster.")
- ruffian ("1. A tough or rowdy person. 2. A thug or gangster.")
- hood (See *hoodlum*.)
- yob ("*Chiefly British slang.* A rowdy, aggressive, or violent young man.")
- bully ("A hired ruffian; a thug.")
- rowdy ("A rough, disorderly person.")
- gorilla ("*Slang:* a. A powerfully built, aggressive, and often crude man. b. A thug.")
- legbreaker ("*Chiefly US slang.* A violent thug, especially one employed as an enforcer by a criminal organization.")

(All except 'legbreaker' op. cit.; 'legbreaker' from [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leg-breaker).)

Comment: In the US a "hoodlum" was apt to simply be a youth gang member, with no especially evil background (though likely moving in that direction), while a "thug" was definitely a bad guy.  (This info, of course, based on TV and the movies, vs any sort of first-hand experience.)

Comment: I quite like "hoodlum" except that it appears to derive from "hood" so might also be seen as a racial slur.  Still, it's the best suggestion so far.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***punk***?

> a petty gangster, hoodlum, or ruffian [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punk)
>
> a criminal or hoodlum [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/punk)

Comment: Yeah, a "punk" was a wannabe -- a young ruffian.

Comment: And then there's the question of how lucky you feel …